# How to pass i18n data to a component as parameter

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

I don't have a lot of experience with i18n and I'm stuck with this.
I have component within another component. All I want to do is to pass i18n as one of the parameters. How do I do that?

Here is what I have:

Component A (Parent)

```
<card content="My text that needs to be transliterated" buttonLabel="Send"></card>
```

Component B (Card - Child)

```
@Input('content') content: string;
@Input('buttonLabel') buttonLabel: string;
```

Normally, I would just `<p i18n="meaning|description@@id">content to be translated</p>`

How can I do that on this case?

Thanks

Comment: From where did you get this usage: <p i18n="meaning|description@@id">content to be translated</p>? Never seen this before

Comment: This is the standard way @RafaeldeCastro: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mark an attribute for translation, add `i18n`-*attribute* in which *attribute* is the attribute to translate. Like in your case with `i18n-`content and `i18n`-buttonLabel:

```
<card 
  i18n-content 
  content="My text that needs to be transliterated"
  i18n-buttonLabel="@@buttonLabelTranslation"
  buttonLabel="Send">
</card>
```

You also can assign a meaning, description, and custom ID with the `i18n`-attribute="`<meaning>|<description>@@<id>`" syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the way we use translation service is like `{{ 'Key' | translate }}` and to simply pass it from parent to child component you can do it as shown below and it will work

```
<card [content]="'YOUR_TRANSLATION_CONTENT_KEY' | translate"  
      [buttonLabel]="'YOUR_TRANSLATION_BUTTON_KEY' | translate">
</card>
```

Comment: I don't recognize the translate pipe from the built-in i18n as the author is using. 
I believe this is ngx-translate?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<ng-container i18n="@@YOUR_TRANSLATION_KEY">Edit</ng-container>
```

You could change `ng-container` with a `div` tag.

Afterward, you can generate the translation file with the following command:

```
ng extract-i18n --format json  --output-path src/locale
```

Whereby format is the format you want